# Cannot find correct adjustment to CSS on togglepanels

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Sorry for asking but I cannot find the correct adjustment to the CSS and I'm pulling my hair out.

On the page [here](http://footy-tipster.co.uk/test-app-page/), there are some toggle panels of the salient wordpress theme. I've customised the panels to my liking, but cannot amend the onhover action where the opacity and color change.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: add the code to your post

Comment: @MélikZarkouna what code would he post if he couldn't find it. Please provide value or don't comment.

Comment: @BlakeConnally i thought he had access the code behind the link he provided !

Comment: @BlakeConnally Stack Overflow strongly recommends a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example be included with the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If the webpage linked is fixed, then this question becomes fairly useless to others. At least include the names of any libraries / plugin's you're using to give a bit of context for the problem. **It is not enough to post a link to an external page and say "how do I fix this?"**

Comment: @Don sure, I agree with your point. But what is the user supposed to do, post a dump of their full site? They couldn't find a style within the page, getting them to post code would be pointless if they don't know what to post.

Comment: Second to last sentance says what to do: "At least include the names of any libraries / plugin's you're using to give a bit of context for the problem." Unless you're implying they wrote the code themselves and didn't know what it did. Seems to me they're wanting to tweak an existing tool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The style for the effect is under the following class. You can add/change this class to change the effect or remove it. On hover it currently transitions to the background color stated below.

```
.toggle h3 a:hover {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.035);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much blake, I was looking in the .toggle h3 area but couldn't find the :hover section to change it. Really appreciate the help.